# Upgrading to IntelliJ 2023.3 crashed my android SDK app settings and now I can't get it to work

Tags: android, intellij-idea, sdk

So I am new to app development and doing this for a school project. I'm developing an app in IntelliJ using android SDK (plugin?). Before updating to IntelliJ 2023.3 everything worked fine (I could run the app, a virtual mobile phone appeared when I did and i could test/play around with the app and had control of it).

[first error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjanT.png)

So after updating IntelliJ to 2023.3 it stopped these links from working in my xml file:

```
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

and i get the error "Resource registered by this uri is not recognized (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs".

I asked Chat-GPT for possible solutions, and none of them worked (Check the XML Namespace, Register the URI, Check the Project Configuration, Ensure Internet Access, XML File Associations, Reload the Project, Check for Plugin Updates).

From here I had created a virtual phone before, but now that is removed:
[second error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aErsv.png)

So now I only get this, and I cant get past this page (don't know what to put here and havent found any clues):

[third error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MY0RZ.png)

I tried all the above solutions and I cant get it to work. Tried opening a new project and cloning it from GitHub, didn't work either. The code works for my friends who haven't updated to IntelliJ 2023.3.

Comment: It could be because of Gradle Plugin Or Gradle Version issue. and your third screenshot shows that you project gradle was not build successful. 

You can try to ```Invalidate Cache And Restart``` android studio from ```File``` menu. or Check the Gradle Settings.

Answer (score 0):

From 2023.3, the Android plugin is not bundled in the IDE, please install it from the IDE via File | Settings | Plugins, search for `Android` and `Android Design Tools`, and then install both plugins.

As an Android developer before, always use Android Studio to develop your Android app, it's officially supported by Google and IDEA's Android support is a bit less stable compared to Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalled and installed 2023.2.5 again and it started working.